# Umbraco Articulate Tags and Categories Returning "System.String[]"

Tags: umbraco, articulate

I am trying to set up a blog using Umbraco and the Articulate plugin. Everything seems to be working great except the Tags and the Categories are returning a string that contains "System.String[]" rather than the values I have assigned to those fields.

I am using Umbraco version 7.6.3 and Articulate version 2.0.5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a bug and you need to disable the new built in property value converters for the categories to work:
https://github.com/Shazwazza/Articulate/issues/233

Comment: How do I disable the new built in property value converters?

Comment: In umbracoSettings.config leave EnablePropertyValueConverters set to false